# $Az + B\overline{z}$ as a linear operator

Tags: complex-numbers, numerical-methods, hilbert-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

Given two matrices $A,B \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ with fixed $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$, let us consider the operator
$$
L:\mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^n,\\
L(z) = Az + B\overline{z}.
$$
This operator is not linear since in general
$$
L(\alpha z) = \alpha Az + \overline{\alpha} B\overline{z} \neq \alpha Az + \alpha B\overline{z} = \alpha L(z)
$$
for $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$.

However, it *is* linear if the scalar body is restricted to $\mathbb{R}$, i.e., if one looks at $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. One can make a Hilbert space of this by attaching the scalar product
$$
\langle z_1, z_2 \rangle := \Re(z_1^H z_2).
$$
(This is indeed a scalar product.)

I'm especially interested in numerical methods for this type of linear operator. Krylov methods translate with no problem, but Gaussian elimination and Multilevel methods, i.e., methods that make direct use of the entries of a matrix, would have to be adapted.

Is anyone aware of work for this type of linear operator?

Comment: I don't follow the structure of the post. Yes, $L$ is $\mathbb{R}$-linear. What does the Hilbert space have to do with $L$?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've adapted the question to better reflect what I'm actually after.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "numerical methods for this type of operator"? Do you want to solve $L(x)=b$? for $x$?

Comment: For example, yes.

Comment: In that case, you can write $L(z)=(A_1+iA_2)(z_1+iz_2)+(B_1+iB_2)(z_1-iz_2)$, $b=b_1+ib_2$, where $\circ_i$ ($i=1,2$) are real. Then $L(z)=b$ is equivalent to the real system $\pmatrix{A_1+B_1&-A_2+B_2\\A_2+B_2&A_1-B_1}\pmatrix{z_1\\z_2}=\pmatrix{b_1\\b_2}$.

Comment: Yes indeed, and while using Gaussian elimination for this matrix would certainly return the correct result, you'd have to perform more work that for a specialized variant of GE for the complex-valued form of the original post.

Comment: You're right, thanks for the hint. In the case you have purely imaginary values on the main diagonal of $A$ and $B=0$ (and thus 0s on the main diagonal), one probably want to sport a 2x2-block version of GE to get the same behavior.